# Lumen 5.8: Implement login

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm new to Lumen. How can I implement login?

I've tried this code but I got an error. And I found out in the documentation that Lumen does not support session. So Auth::attempt() is not available.

```php
public function login(Request $request)
{
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string'
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        if( !Auth::attempt($credentials) ) {
             return response()->json([
                 'message' => 'Unauthorized'
             ], 401);
        }

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully login'], 200);
}
```

How can I authenticate user using login method? Since Auth::attempt() is not working are there any alternatives? Thanks!

Comment: Lumen does not support sessions or persistent authentication out of the box. You will have to create your own implementation.

Comment: I see. So how I can check the credentials of the user?

Comment: You probably need to use Laravel instead of Lumen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take email and password and check in the database manually.

```
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');
    $result = DB::table('users')->where('email', $email)->first();
    if (!is_null($result)) {
        if($password == $result->password) {
            return response(200);
        }
}
```

Checking in table users, in columns email and password.